# Firebase Storage - File error when uploading (Error 400)

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm getting an error when trying to upload a file (like an image) to Firebase Storage. This is weird since I have another component that does it just fine. Here's my code:

```
file: File;

Upload() {

    //Create reference to Firebase Storage
    let storageRef = firebase.storage().ref('Uploads');

    const metadata = {'contentType': this.file.type}

    //Send update to Firebase Storage
    storageRef.put(this.file, metadata);

}

fileListener(event) {
    this.file = event.target.files[0];
    this.upload();
}
```

[image: Error]

Comment: What is in the response message for the 400? 
First thing I would check your security rules configured in firebase storage for this project.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the response message, but [here](https://imgur.com/a/WVwA2) is the error expanded. I just checked the security rules and they allow for unauthenticated submissions.

Comment: In the network tab in chrome, when you click on the 400 response on the right hand side you should see a Response tab that has more info about the 400.

Comment: I'll try that next time. But I figured out that the permissions _were_ restrictive (I was looking at the RTDB's rules earlier) and I redid my code. Looks like it works fine now. Thanks.